# Flutter doesn't delete last item in list

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I have a list which contains widgets (messages) , the problem is that i can't delete last item from list.
I already tried

```
messages.remove(Widget);
messages.removeAt(index);
```

I even tried `messages.clear()`|

But it also doesn't work.... I can delete all message except last one... I also tried change  column to listview.builder... Please give me an advice..

my page code:

```
    ....
    StreamBuilder(
                            stream: _channel.stream,
                            builder:
                                (context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
                              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                RocketChatMessage? mes;
                                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                  try {
                                    var msg = RocketChatMessage.fromJson(
                                        json.decode(snapshot.data));
                                    if (msg.fields != null) {
                                      if (msg.fields!.args![0].msg != null &&
                                          (msg.fields!.args![0].msg!
                                                  .isNotEmpty ||
                                              msg.fields!.args![0].file !=
                                                  null)) {
                                        if (chat.isEmpty) {
                                          chat.add(msg);
                                          messages.add(generateMessage(msg));
                                        } else {
                                          var item = msg.fields!.args![0].sId;
                                          var ex =
                                              chat.last.fields!.args![0].sId;
                                          if (item != ex) {
                                            chat.add(msg);
                                            messages.add(generateMessage(msg));
                                            scrollDown();
                                          }
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                  } catch (e) {
                                    getChatStory(false);
                                    print("story");
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                              
                              return Expanded(
                                  child: Stack(
                                children: [
                                  SingleChildScrollView(
                                    controller: scrollController,
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: messages,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ));
                            } 
                            ),
....
```

Comment: "I have a list which contains widgets" - don't cache any widgets - instead create your widgets list from the scratch inside `build` method

Comment: thakns, i'll try

Comment: @pskink lol, even with list in build method , it still saves last message... Could it be because of streambuilder?

Comment: @pskink i changed StreamBuilder , to usual listener , and seems like working, at least i hope... Either way thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed StreamBuilder , to usual listener , and seems like working

```
_channel.stream.listen((event) {
    RocketChatMessage? mes;
    if (event != null) {
      try {
        var msg = RocketChatMessage.fromJson(json.decode(event));
        if (msg.msg == "changed" && msg.fields != null) {
          if (msg.fields!.args![0].msg != null &&
              (msg.fields!.args![0].msg!.isNotEmpty ||
                  msg.fields!.args![0].file != null)) {
            if (chat.isEmpty) {
              chat.add(msg);
              messages.add(generateMessage(msg));
            } else {
              var item = msg.fields!.args![0].sId;
              var ex = chat.last.fields!.args![0].sId;
              if (item != ex) {
                chat.add(msg);
                messages.add(generateMessage(msg));
              }
            }
            setState(() {});
            scrollDown();
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {
        getChatStory(false);
        print("story");
      }
    }
  });
```

and widget

```
 Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            controller: scrollController,
                            itemCount: chat.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return generateMessage(chat[index]);
                            })),
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have something like `List<Widget> messages`, you can use the dedicated command to remove the last element. It will be `messages.removeLast()`. If this does not answer your questions, please provide more details like the type of your variable `messages`.

Comment: same result....

Comment: List<Widget> messages